# AVL tree rotation function is losing data

Tags: c++, avl-tree

I have an AVL tree and I think my rotation function is losing children somewhere and becomeing disconnected. I cannot find where. Any help is great.

```
void AVL::rotation(Node* rotatedNode, int direction) {
  cout << "rotation ";
  Node* temp;
  if(rotatedNode == nullptr) {
    return;
  }
  //rotation right
  if(direction == 1) {
    cout << "right" << endl;
    if(rotatedNode->leftChild == nullptr){
      return;
    }
    rotatedNode->leftChild->parent = rotatedNode->parent;
    temp = rotatedNode->leftChild->rightChild;
    rotatedNode->leftChild->rightChild = rotatedNode;
    rotatedNode->parent = rotatedNode->leftChild;
    rotatedNode->leftChild = temp;
    if(rotatedNode == root) {
      root = rotatedNode->parent;
    }
  }
  //rotation left
  else {
    cout << "left" << endl;
    if(rotatedNode->rightChild == nullptr){
      return;
    }
    rotatedNode->rightChild->parent = rotatedNode->parent;
    temp = rotatedNode->rightChild->leftChild;
    rotatedNode->rightChild->leftChild = rotatedNode;
    rotatedNode->parent = rotatedNode->rightChild;
    rotatedNode->rightChild = temp;
    if(rotatedNode == root) {
      root = rotatedNode->parent;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You update `rotatedNode->leftChild->parent` to be `rotatedNode->parent` but I don't see anywhere where you set a child node in that parent to point to `leftChild` (similarly for `rightChild` with a left rotation).

Comment: If I but this code

Comment: rotatedNode->parent->leftChild = rotatedNode->leftChild;

Comment: under the line "rotatedNode->leftChild->parent = rotatedNode->parent;" would that work?

Comment: Are you certain the rotated node is the left child of the parent?  Or could it be the right child?

Comment: When I do that I get. seg fault there

Comment: I am not sure there

Comment: in my tree I am adding 1, then 2 , then three, on one and two it works because there is no need to rotate and rebalance, on three though the tree needs to perform a left rotation and it goes to do that and somehow loses the rest of the tree. if I add in the line of code you recommended then it gives me a seg fault and stops there

Comment: Ok i spotted on error, if the rotatedNode is the root we can't make a call for it's parent because it's parent would be nullptr

Comment: OK it is a little better but It is still quickly losing data it now looks like this

Comment: how do I post more code here?